# Finding Points of Inflection (Standard Deviation)

Tags: derivatives

> > Question: A Random Variable that is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ has a probability density function of
> >
> > $$ f(x) = {1\over {\sigma}{\sqrt {2\pi}}} e^{(x-\mu)^2\over 2 \sigma^2} $$
> >
> > Find the values of $x$ where the curve has points of inflection

---

What I have attempted:

$$ f(x) = {1\over {\sigma}{\sqrt {2\pi}}}e^{(x-\mu)^2\over 2{\sigma}^2} $$

$$ f'(x) = {1\over \sigma{\sqrt {2\pi}}}e^{(x-\mu)^2\over 2{\sigma}^2} \cdot {(x-\mu)\over \sigma^2} $$

$$ f''(x) = \left[({1\over \sigma{\sqrt {2\pi}}}e^{(x-\mu)^2\over 2\sigma^2} \cdot {(x-\mu)\over \sigma^2} \cdot {(x-\mu)\over \sigma^2}) + {1\over \sigma{\sqrt {2\pi}}}e^{(x-\mu)^2\over 2\sigma^2} \cdot {1\over \sigma^2}\right] = 0 $$

$$ ({1\over {\sigma}{\sqrt {2\pi}}}e^{(x-\mu)^2\over 2{\sigma}^2}) \left[ {(x-\mu)^2\over {\sigma}^4} + {1\over \sigma^2} \right] = 0 $$

$$ \left[ {(x-\mu)^2\over {\sigma}^4} + {1\over \sigma^2} \right] = 0 $$

$$ \left[ {(x-\mu)^2\over {\sigma}^4} + {\sigma^2\over \sigma^4} \right] = 0 $$

$$  {(x-\mu)^2} + {\sigma^2\ } = 0 $$

$$ x^2 - 2{\mu}x + \mu^2 + {\sigma^2\ } = 0  $$

$$ x={-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a} $$

$$ x={2\mu\pm\sqrt{4\mu^2-4(\mu^2 + \sigma^2) } \over 2} $$

$$ x={2\mu\pm\sqrt{4\mu^2-4\mu^2 - 4 \sigma^2 } \over 2} $$

$$ x={2\mu\pm\sqrt{ - 4 \sigma^2 } \over 2} $$

$$ x={2\mu\pm\ 2\sigma i \over 2} $$

$$ x = \mu ± \sigma i $$

Is this correct? I'm doubting myself due to the fact I have an imaginary number...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your math is correct. There is a typo in the question; a standard Gaussian bell curve should have a negative exponent:
$$
f(x) = {1\over {\sigma}{\sqrt {2\pi}}}e^{-(x-\mu)^2\over 2{\sigma}^2}
$$

Comment: Well... Thanks! Got the right answer now :)